# Finding the position of a character from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried finding the position of a string with charindex function but when there are two letters in the same string, I'm not able to get the code.

My question is:
Find the postion of S from 'SyedSohail'
The output should be
Position
1
5

Could you please help me with the above

I'm writing the code in Tsql

Comment: Why would the position be 15? `'SyedSohail'` doesn't even have 15 characters. The position of the **first** `'S'` in that string is position 1 (it's the first character), so `CHARINDEX('S','SyedSohail')` will return 1. [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Which S? The Sohail's S, or the Syed's S

Comment: @Larnu He's saying he wants to return both 'S' positions at index 1 and 5. Not 15.

Comment: I think he wants to get the index of the `S` character in the whole string, so in this instance, it is in index 1 and 5 (technically should be 0 and 4).

Comment: Ah, wait. You are looking for the position of ALL of the S characters in the string, and want them returned as a list (more commonly shown as `1, 5` instead of `1 5`, but you do not want commas included). This will be a more complex query than a simple `CHARINDEX` lookup, and will require looping of some sort.

Comment: *"and will require looping of some sort."* not nessecarily, @LaughingVergil , as I show in my answer with the Tally (the rCTE *is* a form of looping).

Comment: Maybe this is useful https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41961/how-to-find-all-positions-of-a-string-within-another-string

Comment: In the output it should show the positions of 'S' from SyedSohail @Larnu
Example:- In this string "SyedSohail", S is at 1st position and 5th position so the output should show both the positions 1 and 5.

Comment: @SohailSyed that's what my answers below do for you. Comments are not the location for answers; they're for comments.

Comment: I'm new to this tool @Larnu. I definitely improve myself in future. Please don't be angry on me.

Comment: I'm not angry at all, @SohailSyed , just telling you that these are comments; not answers.

Comment: I think you are the person who has given -1 for the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste the following query right inside your SQL Editor:

```
DECLARE @test AS varchar(100);
DECLARE @ctr as int;
DECLARE @testlength as int;
DECLARE @charToTest as char(1);
DECLARE @positions as varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @findChar as char(1);

SET @test = 'Syed Summers';
SET @ctr = 1;
SET @testlength = LEN(@test) + 1;
SET @positions = '';
SET @findChar = 'S';

WHILE @ctr < (@testlength)
BEGIN
  SET @charToTest = SUBSTRING(@test, @ctr, 1)
  IF (UPPER(@charToTest) = @findChar)
    BEGIN
      SET @positions =  @positions + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ctr)
    END
  SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
END

SELECT RIGHT(@positions, (LEN(@positions) - 1));
```

Explanation:

`@test` - will contain the string which you want to search

`@ctr` - counter to iterate through all the characters in your string `@test`

`@testLength` - length of your `@test` string

`@findChar` - the character which you want to count the instance in the string

`@charToTest` - the string being tested whether it equals your `@findChar` value

`@positions` - will be an enumerated string of the position where the `@findChar` was found in the `@test` string.

Note that I provided a simplistic answer to help guide the understanding for the person who posted the question.

Comment: I really don't suggest this answer. A `WHILE` is a very slow process in an RDBMS. A set based method would be by far a better method.

Comment: I know it is not the best implementation, but given the context of how the question was phrased, I am looking to provide more guidance on how to achieve the desired outcome with very little regard to performance, but more on allowing the person to understand the thought process. I would have used the same answer as what @Larnu posted but I don't feel it is at the level that can be understood by the person who posted the question.

Comment: But with an RDBMS you don't actually *want* to think in loops, @Angelo , you want to think in sets. Thinking in loops is a programmatical thought process, where as you need a set based thought process. Although this does give the OP a solution, I'm just pointing out that loop based solutions, like this, can perform very poorly *because* they are a loop. SQL Server excels at set based operations, and is awful at iterative tasks; and a loop (`WHILE`) is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a function like below,

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FindPatternLocation
(
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @term   NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
    (
      SELECT pos = Number - LEN(@term) 
      FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, Number, 
      CHARINDEX(@term, @string + @term, Number) - Number)))
      FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
      WHERE Number > 1 AND Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@string)+1)
      AND SUBSTRING(@term + @string, Number, LEN(@term)) = @term
    ) AS y);
```

Usage:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SyedSohail'
SELECT pos FROM dbo.FindPatternLocation(@str, 's');
```

[Source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41961/how-to-find-all-positions-of-a-string-within-another-string)

Comment: Surprising that Aaron would post a query with such horrific formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use an rCTE to iterate through the string:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(12) = 'SyedSohail';
DECLARE @Char char(1) = 'S';

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT V.YourString,
           CI.I
    FROM (VALUES(@YourString))V(YourString)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(@Char,V.YourString))) CI(I)
    WHERE CI.I > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.YourString,
           CI.I
    FROM rCTe r
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(@Char,r.YourString,r.I+1))) CI(I)
    WHERE CI.I > 0)
SELECT R.I
FROM rCTE r;
```

However, I suspect ([know for a fact](http://wp.larnu.uk/wp-content/uploads/rCTE-vs-Tally-Small-Intervals-1.png)), a Tally would be quicker with a dataset and/or longer values:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX(LEN(V.YourString)) FROM (VALUES(@YourString))V(YourString)) --Should be from your tablt
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4) --10,000 rows
SELECT T.I
FROM Tally T
     CROSS JOIN (VALUES(@YourString))V(YourString)
WHERE SUBSTRING(V.YourString,T.I,1) = @Char;
```